# Перестает работать тачпад

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Купил ноутбук с сенсорным экраном. Изначально на нем стояла настроенная win10 и всё работало как надо, но мне для работы нужен линукс, поэтому поставил Ubuntu.

И теперь периодически после включения отваливается тачпад. Возможно, как я думаю, это связано из-за тачскрина, может быть он как-то блокирует тачпад.

Когда тачпад работает `xinput` рисует под id 10 и 11 Mouse и Touchpad соответственно, а когда он отваливается, то эти две строчки пропадают и другими утилитами тоже не распознаются.

Тачскрин рисуется под id 9 и 15. Кстати почему 2 раза тоже не ясно, может быть из-за экранной клавиатуры.

Дрова стоят от synaptic.

Ссылка на все логи https://disk.yandex.ru/d/O8InEO99Mhot7A

Comment: я бы предложил сравнить лог иксов, лог ядра и `lsusb`/`lsusb -t` в ситуации, когда тачпад отваливается, а когда нет... ЗЫ: текст лучше приводить текстом, а не картинкой...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Неужели дошли руки собрать все логи, прикрепил ссылку на ЯД. Извините за 4 скриншота, не знаю как копировать из консоли без тачпада.

Comment: с touchscreen'ом это почти наверняка не связано... судя по всему это баг в драйвере... больше всего похоже на [это](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1884288)... какого-либо разумного решения нет, а в качестве workaround'а предлагают выгружать/загружать модуль... также можно попробовать добавить в параметры загрузки `i8042.nopnp`, как предлагает `dmesg` или `i8042.reset`, как предлагается [здесь](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041820/touchpad-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04)... в качестве жеста отчаяния могу также предложить попробовать обновить ядро…

Comment: хотя вот [это](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=208247) даже больше похоже, но в 5.8 он должен быть уже исправлен, так что странно, что он у тебя воспроизводится... ЗЫ: вывод команд получить в виде теста можно перенаправив вывод в файл...

Comment: @Fat-Zer спасибо за наводки, как нибудь покопаюсь. Еще заметил при запуске ОС выползают разные сообщения о фейлах, попробую запечатлеть еще их состаяния.